# How to remove header and footer from Shopify?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I am using Shopify for my online store. I have a header and a footer in all my pages of my website. I want to remove the header and footer in a single page called newadd.

I create an alternative layout, and write code which exclude header and footer. At top of the newadd page I add the code {% layout 'alternative' %}
But it still output header and footer. No effect of alternative layout.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the `{% layout 'alternative' %}` inside the [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) page code. You should add the `{% layout 'alternative' %`} within the template that page is using. Otherwise you can try with with `{% layout none %}` and then call the snippets/templates you like.

Comment: yes sir, i use it bt can't get the result as i want. thnk

Comment: where are you pasting the {% layout 'alternative' %} ?

Comment: At the top of the page, where i want get changed

Comment: yes i add {% layout 'alternative' %} within template template page, it outputs like i not using alternative template. It shows like I am using the main theme

Comment: how to get effect of alternative theme. m not getting it. Actully this project was started by other developer and i have doubt that he did something so i m not getting effect of alternative. plz sorry if i m worng. I m new to shopify

Comment: is there any change or way to stop the effect of other(alternative) theme?

Comment: I repect u sir, bt i can't give u the access.

Comment: No problm my friend. feel free to read my answer and apply what I say there. You have the solution there.

Comment: i didn't add any code then default. it is very very simple code.

Comment: thank u sir, bt i tried {% layout 'alternative' %} and {% layout none%}. sir can i get your any email or any contact ID so that i can contact u if i got some more problems

Comment: I create layout name as alternative. Can I create new template for page called newdisplay(or any different name then alternative)

Comment: I have 3 questions more, upvote all questions and Give the simple Answer and i will  make it valid

Comment: plz upvote my questions.u can see my profile, I am in hold and cannot ask question.

Comment: @narayani did you find the solution?

Comment: Accept my answer and send me an email and I'll help

Comment: Sorry sir i can't bcoz i didn't got my answer.

Comment: then I can't help either via email :-(